# How to use code to apply to all .txt files in directory and append one data frame per file in R?

Tags: r

Okay, so this is a bit of a loaded question and am not really sure how to start...
So, from the beginning, I have let's say 3 .txt files (but there are actually many more) in my directory. The layout of the text files are the same but the numbers are different. I was able to manipulate the files one at a time using my code but this becomes unreasonable because I would need to manually append the rows for each consecutive .txt file into one data frame. How can I apply my current code to work with one text file at a time, make a data frame, move on to the next text file, and then append it to the rows of the original data frame?

For example...

```
"sample1.txt"
"sample2.txt"
"sample3.txt"
```

sample1 lines are read and made into a data frame.

```
ID picture color
1     1     red
1     2     red
1     3     blue
```

Now that task is done and I have a data frame I like. Now, What kind of loop or function do I need to write to do the same code on the next text file in line and append it to the first to be something like this?...

```
  ID picture color
    1     1     red
    1     2     red
    1     3     blue
    2     1     red
    2     3     blue
    2     4     green
```

And so on and so forth for the rest of the files?

Here is my code below. It's lengthy and may not make all complete sense...

```
#set up working directory, files, and save path and name
list.of.packages = c("dplyr", "berryFunctions", "stringr","gsubfn")
new.packages = list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
if(length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages)

library ("berryFunctions")
library("stringr")
library("dplyr")
library("gsubfn")
wd <- "C:/Users/PC/Desktop/New folder/GoD/" #change this to where the raw text files are located
setwd(wd)
Export_File_Name <- "GameOfDice_CATCH-018-1.txt" #name of raw file
csvname <- "output.csv" #name of save output file
files <- list.files(pattern = "*.txt") #name of files
#############################################################
#change files to utf8 and the change directory
if (file.exists("./utf8dir")) {unlink("./utf8dir", recursive = TRUE)}

convert_file_to_utf8 <- function(in_file, out_file, encoding = "utf-16") {
  in_file_conn <- file(in_file, encoding = encoding)
  txt <- readLines(in_file_conn)
  close(in_file_conn)
  
  # Create out directory
  if (!dir.exists(dirname(out_file))) dir.create(dirname(out_file))
  
  # Write file with new encoding
  out_file_conn <- file(out_file, encoding = "utf-8")
  writeLines(txt, out_file_conn)
  close(out_file_conn)
}

create_utf8_dir <- function(in_dir = "./utf16dir/", out_dir = "./utf8dir/") {
  files <- dir(in_dir, full.names = TRUE)
  for (in_file in files) {
    out_file <- sub(in_dir, out_dir, in_file, fixed = TRUE)
    convert_file_to_utf8(in_file, out_file)
  }
}
create_utf8_dir(wd)
wd <- "C:/Users/PC/Desktop/New folder/GoD/utf8dir/"
setwd(wd)
savepath <- "C:/Users/PC/Desktop/New folder/GoD/utf8dir/save/" #set to same as "wd" but with "save" added. we'll make that folder later
if (file.exists("./save")) {unlink("./save", recursive = TRUE)}
dir.create(paste(wd,"save",sep="/"))
#############################################################
# file_func <- function(wd)({
  files <- list.files(pattern = "*.txt")
  df_delim <- read.delim(files)
  df_delim <- as.data.frame(df_delim)
  colnames(df_delim) <- c("Header_Start")
  df_delim$Header_Start <- as.character(df_delim$Header_Start)
  df_delim <- subset(df_delim,Header_Start != "")
  dat <- df_delim
  
  dat <- insertRows(dat, 1 , new = NA)
  dat[1,] <- colnames(dat)
  colnames(dat) <- c("1")
  df <- dat
  df$`1` <- gsub("X....","",df$`1`)
  df$`1` <- gsub("[....^]","",df$`1`)
  df$`1` <- gsub("[***]","",df$`1`)
  df$'2' <- NA 
  df[c('1', '2')] <- str_split_fixed(df$'1', ':', 2)
  df$`1` <- gsub("X....","",df$`1`)
  df$`2` <- gsub("X....","",df$`2`)
  df$`1` <- gsub("[....^]","",df$`1`)
  df$`2` <- gsub("[....^]","",df$`2`)
  df$`1` <- gsub("[***]","",df$`1`)
  df$`2` <- gsub("[***]","",df$`2`)
  df$`1` <- gsub("\\s","",df$`1`)
  df$`2` <- gsub("\\s","",df$`2`)
  df$`1` <- gsub("\\.","_",df$`1`)
  df$`1` <- gsub("\\s","_",df$`1`)
  df$`1` <- gsub("-","_",df$`1`)
  df$`2` <- gsub("\\{","",df$`2`)
  df$`2` <- gsub("\\}","",df$`2`)
  rownames(df) <- NULL
  firstrows <- as.data.frame(df[1:24,1])
  secondrows <- as.data.frame(df[1:24,2])
  bound_rows <- as.data.frame(cbind(firstrows,secondrows))
  colnames(bound_rows) <- c("1", "2")
  df <- df[-c(1:24),]
  df <- slice(df, 1:(n() - 22))
  
  c=1
  for (row in 1:nrow(df)){
    if (df[row,'1']=='LogFrameStart' &
        df[row+1,'1'] == 'Procedure'){
      sample_data = df[row:(row+30),]
      
      if (c==1){
        newdata = sample_data
        c=c+1
      } else { newdata = cbind(newdata,sample_data[,2])}
    }
  }
  
  data1 <- newdata
  n_col <- seq(ncol(data1[,2:ncol(data1)]))
  labels <- data1[,1]
  data1 <- data1[,-1]
  colnames(data1) <- n_col
  data1 <- cbind(labels,data1)
  data1 <- data1[-1,]
  data1 <- slice(data1, 1:(n() - 2))
  data1 <- t(data1)
  colnames(data1) <- data1[1,]
  rownames(data1) <- NULL
  data1 <- data1[-1,]
  rownames(data1) <- NULL
  rownames(data1)
  data1 <- as.data.frame(data1)
  data1$Trial <- rownames(data1)
  data1 <- data1 %>%
    select(Trial, everything())
  data1$Subject <- NA
  data1 <- data1 %>%
    select(Subject, everything())
  
  fill <- as.character(strapplyc(files, "-(.*)-", simplify = TRUE))
  data1$Subject <- fill
```

Comment: Please don't put lengthy code that's mostly unrelated in your question. Instead, try to create a **minimal** reproducible example.

Comment: Generally, I'd point you to my answer at [How do I make a list of data frames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames). A common and good approach is to put each of your sub data frames in to a list - which could be done in a loop or with an `lapply()`, and then at the end combine them into one big data frame.

Comment: Pseudo code for that would be `results <- list()` then `for(i in seq_along(files)) {... code reading and transforming files[i]...; results[[i]] <- ..this result..}` then `big_result = do.call(rbind, results)`